# If we were given differences in variances, and power, find n?

Tags: statistical-significance, statistical-power, type-i-and-ii-errors, f-distribution

If we have a given difference in the variances *x* and 80% power, how would you find the sample size needed to detect the difference in variances equal to *x*? I know that power = 1-P(type II error) but I only know how to apply this with difference in means. I think that I would have to use the F distribution somehow but I'm not sure how to. Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the F could apply under a normal assumption (to which it is sensitive) for a *ratio* of variances (rather than a difference).

A difference in variances would have to be scaled somehow (otherwise the distribution of the test statistic would depend on the common variance under the null), and would not use an F distribution.

If you have the original data there are other approximate equality-of-variance tests which are less sensitive to the normality assumption.

[You might also consider a permutation test as a possibility; this can deal with a difference in variance and would be straightforward if you assume equal means under the null. There are also some rank-based tests for spread.]

To really pin this down you'd have to be very clear whether or not you really wanted a difference in variances for a statistic or whether other tests for equality of variances would suit; whether or not you're prepared to make a strong distributional assumption.

It may also be important to know why you're testing variance. For example, if you're just checking assumptions of some other procedure, my advice would be not to test that but to avoid the assumption if at all possible.